A late 90's or early 2000's werewolf movie
I've seen this movie long time ago and I only remember bits and pieces of this movie. I remember few scenes from the movie and before explaining the scenes I'd like to tell that it might be a B - movie, poor CGI and might be a low rated movie.
Few scenes I remember.
Scene 1 - Lead(male) goes into a tunnel or a cave with is very dark and gets exposed to some sort of light(appear like a sunshine) and turns into a werewolf.
After he becomes a werewolf, he starts killing people( without being aware of) and turns into a man and he starts seeing dead people(probably the ones he killed.).
Scene 2 - Lead sees as dead woman with scars on her face and body and while she sneezes, her eye falls down on the ground with cord attached and she tries to put back her eye along with the cord.
Scene 3 - Lead lady friend(probably know that lead is a werewolf) put some meat pieces into a blender and grinds it and put the juice in a glass and gives it to lead(I don't remember whether he drinks it or not) and she sits astride on the lead while he's laying on the bed and she removes her top and places both palms of the lead on her bare breasts and talks something.
Scene 4 - Lead and his lady friend fight with some guys underground and remember the lady has a torch(not electrical) in her hand and they kiss and tries to take off their cloths.
Scene 5(climax scene) - (the climax scene is shot in the subway(a train car)) In the train a bad guy starts beating the lead repeatedly and lead gets angry and turns into a werewolf and the bad guy falls down on his stomach and lead runs his claws on the bad guy's back and tears him apart.
That's all I remember.  

Sounds like "An American Werewolf in London", especially the first scenes.

Thank you for asking this question. I was looking for the name of this movie but realized that I only remembered the breast part. :P

It doesn't match all your criteria, but how about An American Werewolf in Paris?

From the Wikipedia page, your Scene 1:

...That night, Andy, Chris, and Brad attend a night club called "Club
  de la Lune". The club's owner, Claude, is actually the leader of a
  werewolf society that uses the club as a way to lure people
  (preferring tourists) in to be killed. Serafine arrives, tells Andy to
  run away and transforms into a werewolf. The club owners transform
  into werewolves as well and butcher all the guests. Chris escapes but
  is later kidnapped by Claude, Brad's heart is eaten by a werewolf and
  Andy is bitten by another werewolf.

The above scene takes place in a cavern, similar to a cave.
This next scene matches part of your Scene Three:

The next day, Andy wakes up at Serafine's house. He is still in shock,
  but Serafine allows him to feel her breasts to calm him down. She
  tells him he's transforming into a werewolf.

As finally the ending matches the sounds of your Scene Five:

Claude makes his way onto a subway train, but slips onto the tracks. A
  train slams into him, causing him to transform back to a human. He
  tries to take another dose of the drug, but Andy stops him. As they
  fight, Andy discovers that Claude is the werewolf that bit him. Andy
  then kills him and eats his heart, breaking the werewolf curse.
  Serafine is taken in an ambulance, but begins to show signs of
  transforming. The EMT, thinking she is going into shock, administers
  adrenaline, which stops the transformation - where the "cure" (which
  turned out to be a sedative) triggered the change, adrenaline has the
  opposite effect.

It was released in 1997, so matches that criteria as well.
You can view the trailer here.

Man! this is it, "An American Werewolf in Paris" is correct. +1 for the trailer which brought all my memories back. I've seen "Julie Delpy" in so many movies but still didn't remember that she was the actress in this one.

No worries, glad I could help :)
